# Qt Creator Debugger Views become Disabled

Tags: qt, debugging, qt-creator

While debugging in Qt Creator (ver 3.4.2), if I hit the escape key (which I tend to do often to declutter my work space), then all of the debugger views including the debugger toolbar become hidden (as expected), but later I can't get them back. If I go under Qt Creator's main menu->Window, then Views is disabled.

Here's an example of a basic window before I click the escape key. Notice I have all of the debugging views showing (i.e. Breakpoints, Stack, Locals and Expressions, etc...)

[image]

Here's an example of my window after I've clicked the escape key. Notice how all of the debugging windows are hidden (as expected). My question is, now how do I get the windows back? You can see how the "Views" submenu under the "Window" menu is disabled.

[image]

Is there some sort of "Show Debugger Toolbar" keyboard shortcut? Or is there another menu somewhere to get this back? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Under the Window menu, enable Show Mode Selector. This will show a strip down the left of your window where you should see a Debug tab you can click on to put Qt Creator back in Debug mode.